# Cannot Connect Data Source In Spring

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-data, datasource

I cann't get datasource connection from spring.xml.And tried testing with @Repository ,@Service but it didn't work.How do I fix this problem? Please Let me know how to solve this problem. Thanks

**spring.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
   <context:annotation-config/>

   <context:component-scan base-package="org.minthurein.javabrains" />

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
     <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"></property>   
     <property name="username" value="postgres" ></property>
     <property name="password" value="123" ></property>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**jdbcDaoImpl.java**

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import org.minthurein.javabrains.model.Circle;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    @Component
    public class jdbcDaoImpl {
        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource; 

        public Circle getCricle(int circleId){
        Connection conn=null;
        Statement stmet=null;
    //  System.out.println("ID"+circleId);

        try{
          conn = dataSource.getConnection();
          System.out.println(conn+">>>>>>>");
          conn.setAutoCommit(false);
          stmet = conn.createStatement();
          String sql="SELECT * FROM circle WHERE ID="+circleId;
          Circle circle=null;   
          ResultSet rs=stmet.executeQuery(sql);
          if(rs.next())
          {
             //  System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
             circle=new Circle(circleId,rs.getString("name"));
          }
      rs.close();
      stmet.close();
      conn.commit();
      return circle;
    }
```

**Error Console**

[image]

Comment: Why is your bean org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource, but your `@Autowired` is "javax.sql.DataSource;"?

Comment: @JonahCui That seems correct

Comment: context:component-scan was introduced in Spring 2.5 - what version are you using ?

Comment: i used spring-framework-4.3.4.RELEASE.

Comment: Could u tell me is there something wrong in my xml.

Comment: Please copy stacktraces and similar as text/code and not as images. Much easier to work with

Comment: Does jdbcDaoImpl get instantiated by Spring? Please mark the line where the NPE occurs.

Comment: Mind explaining why you reverted my edit?

Comment: I think exception is occurs when trying to get connection from conn = dataSource.getConnection(); because next line syso is not even printed out on console. Can you please check is dataSource is null or not?

Comment: i didn't make revert. What do u mean @JensSchauder? And i don't know how to use stacktraces. Thanks

Comment: dataSource is in Spring.xml.Did u mean that? @newuserua_ext

Comment: @ThuRein not a complete revert, but most of the formatting I did is gone again. See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41255531/revisions

Comment: I see.  @JensSchauder

Comment: I think this is not null pointer exception. Null pointer exception occour in error console because i cann't connect with datasource from spring.xml. Please help me.

Comment: I Got It.Thanks to all.